# Formula for excel - find and replace rest of string

Tags: excel, string, formula

could somebody help. In Excel I need a formula to find and replace rest of string.

For example I have in column:
Daily (Front Wheels)
Daily (Rear Inner Wheels)
Daily (Rear Wheels)
etc.

By formula SUBSTITUTE I can only remove or change specific string. 
I would like to remove rest of string from one.

For example on the first line is:
Daily (Front Wheels)
and I want to remove everything from " (" to have just - "Daily"

Formula like this doesn´t work:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1;" (*";"")
```

So I´m looking for a code which will find some sting and from this string remove rest of it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following formula should help:

```
=TRIM(LEFT(A1;SEARCH("(";A1)-1))
```

Comment: Perftect. Thank you.